# $ \displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \frac{(a-b-c)^2}{2a^2+(b+c)^2}\geq \frac{1}{2}$ with C-S

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

This almost feels like it could work so I'm curious if it actually might. We also know $a$,$b$,$c >0$.

By Cauchy-Schwarz \begin{align} \text{LHS} \geq \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)+(a+b+c)^2}\end{align}

And this looks very familiar since we know $3(a^2+b^2+c^2)+(a+b+c)^2\geq 2(a+b+c)^2$ but if we flip them $A>B\geq 0\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{A}< \frac{1}{B}$ the order changes. I'm curious if I can do something in these cases.

This is from a book so I have a proof of it already. What I'm looking for is if I can continue from that first application of C-S i.e., $$\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)+(a+b+c)^2} \geq \frac{1}{2}$$

Another thing, I'm new to solving inequalities, how should I test if this bound even works? In some cases it is easy but here I can think of how.

Comment: Looking at it a bit more, I don't think it works. I'd need to show $(a+b+c)^2 \geq 3(a^2+b^2+c^2)$ but that is true only when $a=b=c$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(b+c-a)^2}{2a^2+(b+c)^2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(b+c-a)^2(b+c)^2}{2a^2(b+c)^2+(b+c)^4}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(b+c-a)(b+c)\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2(b+c)^2+(b+c)^4)}=\frac{4(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(4a^2b^2+4a^2bc+2a^4+4a^3b+4a^3c+6a^2b^2)}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$4(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2\geq\sum_{cyc}(a^4+2a^3b+2a^3c+5a^2b^2+2a^2bc)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(3a^4-2a^3b-2a^3c+3a^2b^2-2a^2bc)\geq0$$ or
$$2\sum_{cyc}(a^4-a^3b-a^3c+a^2bc)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a^2-b^2)^2+2\sum_{cyc}c^2(a-b)^2\geq0$$
which is true by Schur.

Now, we see that the starting inequality is true for any reals $a$, $b$ and $c$

such that $\prod\limits_{cyc}\left(2a^2+(b+c)^2\right)\neq0$.

Comment: Can downvoter explain me why did you do it?

Comment: (+1) for nice C-S. They should not downvote a correct answer. If they don't like the answer, I think they can just ignore it.

Comment: @River Li     Maybe do you know,  which nick-name has  TATA box on AoPS?

Comment: I don't Exactly know. By the way, today, TATA box, Anonymous, Dragon boy and Inequality , these four accounts are temporarily suspended for voting irregularities. The suspension period ends on Sep 10. I don't know what happened.

Comment: Wow! It's very strange. Thank you

Comment: @River Li Yes, I have checked it. You are right. These four love inequalities and I am sure that it's just an attack against inequalities. OK. This site got a ban from me

Comment: Oh, I found one more. [Trần Nk Trang](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1181885/tr%e1%ba%a7n-nk-trang) account is temporarily suspended for voting irregularities. The suspension period ends on Sep 10.

Comment: You answered inequality from the title, but not the actual question (which asks if it is possible to prove/continue from $\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)+(a+b+c)^2} \geq \frac{1}{2}$). Some people only read titles I guess. But... OP accepted the answer anyway so it doesn't matter (I guess they realized this inequality is wrong).

Comment: Yup, that’s what happened.